# ClassicThesis: "Part" titlepage structure

Tags: classicthesis

Calling all ClassicThesis users, I need a tweak for my PhD thesis. I want to add some text (a quote) in the titlepage of each Part, *before* the part number and title, and keep the short description after it as well. The relevant block of code in classicthesis.sty is

```
\newcommand{\ct@parttext}{\relax}
\newcommand{\ctparttext}[1]{\renewcommand{\ct@parttext}{#1 \relax}} 
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\normalfont\centering\large}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}
    {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}[\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize\color{Black}\begin{quote}\ct@parttext \end{quote}]
```

How do I edit it to create *two* boxes of text, one before and one after the part title? Changing the definition of \ctparttext seems like a terrible idea here...

Comment: You're using an older version of CT, right? @Paul answer is for the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do two things:

- Define a new set of commands (based on `\ctparttext`) to "hold" your quotation.
- Modify the `titleformat` for `part` to use them, again by analogy to the existing definition.

---

```
\makeatletter
   \def\ct@partquotekeep{\relax}
   \def\ct@partquoteprint{\ct@partquotekeep\gdef\ct@partquotekeep{\relax}}
   \newcommand{\ctpartquote}[1]{\renewcommand{\ct@partquotekeep}{#1}} 
   \titleformat{\part}[display]
        {\color{Black}\begin{quote}\normalfont\normalsize\ct@partquoteprint\end{quote}\bigskip\ct@altfont\centering\large}
        {\thispagestyle{empty}\normalfont\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}
        {\color{CTtitle}\spacedallcaps}[\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize\color{Black}\begin{quote}\ctparttext@print \end{quote}]
    \makeatother
```

This is now used as follows:

```
\ctpartquote{What could be more precious than a lovely quotation for your Part.

\hfill --- \textsc{famous author}}
\ctparttext{This is the part text. This is the part text. This is the part text.}

\part{Part One}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed! I had to change a few details in your code but it works as expected.